# Prisma QueryRawUnsafe testing

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, prisma

I'm trying to test a function that uses queryRawUnsafe using prismock and for some reason it doesn't read correctly when I run the test. Right now in the test if I use

```
await DBConn.table_name.findMany()
```

it works properly and returns all records, however, if I do

```
await DBConn.$queryRawUnsafe(`SELECT * FROM table_name`)
```

it returns nothing, but also no errors, does anyone know how to fix this problem?

This is how I mock the prisma client

```
jest.mock('@prisma/client', () => {
    return {
        ...jest.requireActual('@prisma/client'),
        PrismaClient: jest.requireActual('prismock').PrismockClient,
    };
});
```

My current theory is that prismock doesn't understand the $. syntax?

Answer (score 0):

`prismock` package does not support mock `$queryRawUnsafe()` method, see [issues#731](https://github.com/morintd/prismock/issues/731).

The author suggests using `jest.spyOn(prisma, '$queryRawUnsafe').mockResolvedValue(YOUR_EXPECTED_VALUE)` to mock the `$queryRawUnsafe()` method and its resolved value.